# load css file conditionally

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a simple way to load some css files based on a condition

for example :

This is my site  :

```
     www.example.com/en <------------
```

**en** is our language , it can be **fr** or **tr** or whatever ,

no can we say ?

```
   if (en){
         load this css file

    }else{
         load another css file

    }
```

I want this to work in a Php MVC environment , and this css files are tweeter bootstrap which are Rtl or ltr in grid flow order(direction).

I have access to **en**  as a variable , So I know if it is en or whatever
But I think page loading stops until all css files has been downloaded

Comment: `css files load before any php scripts starts to load` Nope. PHP loads before CSS :)

Comment: Hmm , a little bad explanation by me , I'll edit

Comment: @DaveChen true so in that case you can use php to give you the right css file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a php function to give you the right css file which you can then echo onto your page

**PHP**

```
function getCSSUrl($lang){
    $cssBase = "www.example.com/css/";

    switch($lang){
        case "en":
          return $cssBase."en.css";
        case "fr":
          return $cssBase."fr.css";
        case "ru":
          return $cssBase."ru.css";
        default:
          return $cssBase."en.css"; 
    }   
}
```

**yourview.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
            href="<?php echo getCSSUrl($_GET['lang']); ?>">
    </head>

    <body>
    ....
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this will cause bad use experience 
page loads without css files first , and after a few seconds , css will load  ? hmmm ?

Comment: No. the `yourview.php` file is sent through the php parser and all the php code is evaluated and added to the html. And then it is sent to the browser. It doesn't send the html output and then evaluate the php and then send that

Answer (score 3):

Since you can link a css file using

Then you can `switch()` in php, such that:

```
<php

swith( $en )
{

case "en":
 echo " <link rel='stylesheet'.../> "; //load for English
 break;


case "Fr":
 echo " <link rel='stylesheet'.../> "; //load for French 
 break;


case "gr":
 echo " <link rel='stylesheet'.../> "; //load for Greek :p)
 break;

}

?>
```

should take care of it.