# click on link -> set cookie -> additional stylesheet loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I wrote my static site using [hugo](https://hugo.io). Since I prefer the historical default layout I'm perfectly fine with it *and I don't want to change it*.

But some readers prefer a more modern layout. I created it, let's call it `pretty.css`. (It's just next to my other css, which is called `basic.css`.)

I want to create a link. When this link is clicked, a cookie should be set. When this cookie is set, `pretty.css` has to be added to the stylesheets.

There has to be a second link, which removes that cookie.

Comment: could you share any code samples you have tried ? because setting and reading cookies can be found easily online, and in your case, if it's, say php backend, you need a solution like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820724/load-css-file-conditionally

Comment: @LoneWolf but can this be done by JS only? I am not writing any backend.

Comment: yes, updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure js way to read/set cookie and load css dynamically based on that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var preferredCss = getCookie('preferred_css');
    if (!preferredCss || preferredCss.length == 0) 
        preferredCss = 'basic.css';

    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+preferredCss+'" />');



    function setCookie(name,value) {
       var expires = "";
       var date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime() + (60*24*60*60*1000));
       expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
       document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
    }
    function getCookie(c_name) {
        if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
            c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
            if (c_start != -1) {
                c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
                c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
                if (c_end == -1) {
                    c_end = document.cookie.length;
                }
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
   function deleteCookie(name) {
      document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;path=/';
   };
```

Now, when user clicks on the link to set pretty.css, you just need to call setCookie like this,

```
setCookie('preferred_css','pretty.css');
```

and to delete cookie, call

```
deleteCookie('preferred_css');
```

Comment: this works for the current page, and it works well. thanks!
But I would prefer this to work **site-wide**.

Comment: if you have a home.html or a common parent html file, include that code there, so it will work across all pages

Comment: What works: setting the cookie from anywhere. What not works: deleting the cookie from anywhere, getCookie from anywhere. I guess, this is about the var `document.cookie`

Comment: there was a mistake with deleteCookie that I corrected now (added path=/). you should now be able to delete cookie from anywhere in the site.